# Is it possible to have a SeekBar's thumb image extend outside the bar?

Tags: android, offset, seekbar, margins

I have set negative paddings on my custom seekbar so that the round thumb image can go outside the bar, but the thumb isn't rendered out there, is there anyway to force the thumb to be drawn outside those bounds?

Sorry guys, I'm new to Android development, and have been tasked with fixing an existing application. The problem is that we have a custom rounded looking track bar, which consists of two rounded 'end cap' images and a 1 px background that is tiled to create the seekbar. As far as I can tell there was never one image that could be set as the background of a normal SeekBar, which is why a custom one was created.

The thumb is a circle and needs to 'fit' into the end caps - the three pieces of the bar are in a relative layout. Right now I'm kind of unclear as to how the 1 px background png gets stretched as the seekbar bg, otherwise I would try to tack on the two endcaps onto that drawable some how ... ?

Please let me know if this was unclear and I'll try to post any followup info. Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Oh, I'm using Android 2.1 if that's relevant to anyone's interests :)

This is what it looks like when the thumb all the way over - outside of the seekbar. Ideally what I need is for the thumb to be shown as 'inside' the endcap image :-/

[image]

Comment: It might help to add some screenshots showing the problem, and what you would like it to look like.

Comment: I added a link to the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, my thumb is very big length wise and it kept being cut off.  Make sure that you set the offset property AFTER you set the drawable for your thumb, like this:

```
seek.setThumb(Main.app.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb));
seek.setThumbOffset(15);
```

This will set the correct offset when your thumb is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the thumb offset property, after that it will not go off from the seek bar

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.  I was able to get satisfactory results by using `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` within the XML.